# Yammer integration with Dell Boomi

Tags: yammer

I am trying to integrate Yammer with Dell Boomi. Using a HTTP client in Boomi, I am trying to access Yammer, but I am getting an unauthorised access. Please find below the Error:

**Error message received from Http Server, Code 401: Unauthorized; Caused by: Error message received from Http Server, Code 401: Unauthorized**

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks,
Veena.

Comment: Can you provide significantly more detail about the problem you're having, detailed steps to recreate what you've done so far, and the steps you've unsuccessfully taken to resolve it?

Comment: Here is the documentation for authenticating with the Yammer API. http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-oauth2. Please make sure you've followed these steps. Come back with details about where this workflow is failing for you and maybe we can help.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Here are more details. I am configuring the yammer as a Http Client in Dell Boomi and trying to connect to Yammer from Dell Boomi. The following are the configurations given:              URL :https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json?access_token=,Authentication Type is OAuth,Request Token URL is https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json?, Give the Consumer Key, Secret key and the Access Token. @Marco: I have followed the same steps, but one thing which I am not able to get is token secret value from the above steps.